# Leet Code question 3. Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters

Tags: java

[image]

Given a string s, find the length of the longest
substring
without repeating characters.

Example 1:

Input: s = "abcabcbb"
Output: 3
Explanation: The answer is "abc", with the length of 3.
Example 2:

Input: s = "bbbbb"
Output: 1
Explanation: The answer is "b", with the length of 1.
Example 3:

Input: s = "pwwkew"
Output: 3
Explanation: The answer is "wke", with the length of 3.
Notice that the answer must be a substring, "pwke" is a subsequence and not a substring.

Constraints:

0 <= s.length <= 5 * 104
s consists of English letters, digits, symbols and spaces.

```
class Solution 
{
    public boolean validate(String ret, String s, char temp)
    {
            for(int j = 0; j < ret.length(); j++)
            {
                if(ret.charAt(j) == temp)
                {
                    return true;
                }

            }

        return false;
    }

    public int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) 
    {
        String  ret = new String();
        boolean flag = false;
        char temp;
        int highest = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 1; j <  s.length(); j++) 
            {
                ret = s.substring(i,j);

                if(ret.length() > 1 && ret.length() < s.length()-1)
                {
                    if(validate(ret, s, s.charAt(j+1)))
                        if(ret.length() > highest)
                            highest = ret.length();
                }
                    
            }      
        } 

        return highest;
    }
}
```

```
Runtime Error
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 8 out of bounds for length 8
  at line 55, java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$1.apply
  at line 52, java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$1.apply
  at line 213, java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$4.apply
  at line 210, java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$4.apply
  at line 98, java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds
  at line 106, java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex
  at line 302, java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex
  at line 4828, java.base/java.lang.String.checkIndex 
  at line 46, java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt
  at line 1555, java.base/java.lang.String.charAt
  at line 32, Solution.lengthOfLongestSubstring
  at line 54, __DriverSolution__.__helper__
  at line 84, __Driver__.main
```

Comment: Look at  `s.charAt(j+1)` What is the value of `j+1` on the last iteration of your loop?

Comment: @David No that's too general

Comment: @Mitch: Then what *specifically* are you asking?  This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: @PM77-1 I think this error is solved when I made the J loop go till length-1. now it's complaining about the ret = s.substring(i,j); line. java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: Range [2, 1) out of bounds for length 8

Comment: @David do you recommend any specific debugger?

Comment: @Mitch: No, but your favorite search engine can help you find modern IDEs for Java development, as well as guides and tutorials for using them.

Comment: "Range [2, 1) out of bounds for length 8" means you can't have an end that is less than the start.

Comment: Please get rid of the images in your question. The question body has a text copy of the stack trace, so there is a redundancy. And [text is preferred to an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Instead of showing an image of your source code with the problem line highlighted, highlight with a comment in your code.

Comment: For reference: https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/description/

Answer (score -3):

### sliding window technique

```
class Solution {
    public int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        int ans=0;
        Map<Character,Integer> map=new HashMap<>();
        while(j<s.length()){
            map.put(s.charAt(j),map.getOrDefault(s.charAt(j),0)+1);
            while(map.get(s.charAt(j))>1){
              map.put(s.charAt(i),map.getOrDefault(s.charAt(i),0)-1);
              i++;
            }
            ans=Math.max(ans,j-i+1);
            j++;
        }
        return ans;
        
    }
}
```

Time complexity --> O(n)

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: I am trying to fix my own solution

Comment: Don’t just submit code without an explanation.  Stack Overflow isn’t a “do my work for me” site.  Explain what was wrong with the code in the question, and explain what you changed and why.